# How to 'AWAIT' for the response of API before call again the function in **SET-INTERVAL**

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await, setinterval

I am using **async and await**, in order to call the same API but from different dates for ex. ->

Suppose user want to see the table data from `01/02/2020 - 20/02/20`, So I want to hit API 21 times, by passing each day one by one. So, I used `setInterval(fun, 1000)`. But AWAIT will not work in interval.
See the code below ->

```
//fromDate = date selected by user. (for ex 01/02/2020)
//momentToDate = the last date set by user. (for ex. 20/02/20)
//endDate = fromDate + 1 (in order to get one day data from API)

         function onClickGetDateByFilter() {
            setComapreTableLoading(true);
            let endDate = moment(fromDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
            var callInterval = setInterval(async () => {
                endDate = moment(endDate).add(1, 'days');
                if (endDate <= momentToDate) {
                    let date = { fromDate, toDate: endDate }

                    await getDataWithClientId('clientID', date)
                        .then(async (res) => {

                            if (res.results && res.results.length > 0) {
                                setClientData({...clientData}, res.results)
                                setComapreTableLoading(false);
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            setComapreTableLoading(false);
                            console.log(err);
                            alert(err);
                        })
                }
                else {
                    setComapreTableLoading(false);
                    clearInterval(callInterval)
                };
            }, 1000)
       }
```

I need to call setInterval upto the last date selected by user. but with the above approach, before getting the response from server it keep call a new API, But I want to call the API second time only after the first API return the response.

Any suggestion will also be appreciated.
Thanks.

**If you need more info regarding code, you can ask.**

Comment: Since you mean external module named `async` you do need to install and import it.

Comment: async is a reserved keyword in JS, however async.parallel is an npm package you need to install and then import from using
import parallel from 'async/parallel'

Comment: You need to install `npm install async` and import `async`

Comment: Why not use promise.all ?

Comment: But we generally use async-await in the functions without installing any dependency, so why in this case I need to install? @YuryTarabanko

Comment: @RajatSharma It is unfortunate but there is a library named `async` that you can import and use. It implements the `async.parallel` function. The `async` keyword has nothing to do with `async.parallel`

Comment: Because `async.parallel` has nothing to do with `async-await`. It is just a module named `async`

Comment: like what said  @Yury Tarabanko you need to require/import the module to be able to use it

Comment: The `async` library from where `async.parallel` comes from is this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async. It is also sometimes referred to as caolan/async to avoid confusion with `async` keyword

Comment: Oh, damn! I thought It is the same as Async we normally use and even the editor is showing me all the predefined methods like parallel,series and all.
Thanks all of you to let me know this.

Comment: Can you please reveiw the question again and help me to solve this new one? @slebetman

Comment: Can you please reveiw the question again and help me to solve this new one? @xMayank

Comment: And what about this new one? @epascarello

Answer (score 0):

Async is a utility module which provides straight-forward, powerful functions for working with asynchronous JavaScript.

You need the Async package to use the parallel method.

> $ npm install async

`import async from 'async';`

---

Async package is not to be confused with asynchronous functions, because the package **Async** has nothing to do with `async-await`.

Source: https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html

Comment: Yes, I thought it is same as Async we normally use. Even the editor is showing me the predefined methods of it even without installing it.
My bad.

Comment: Can you please reveiw the question again and help me to solve this new one? @PatricNox